# i am trying to pass 3 variables in javascript [codeigniter post method]

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

It's a like dislike button, connected with a database. But it only takes the first variable "storyid".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function savelike(storyid, username, autid)
{
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('site/homecontroler/savelikes');?>",
                Data: "Storyid="+storyid,
                success: function (response) {
                 $("#like_"+storyid).html(response+" Likes");

                }
            });
}
</script>
```

```
 <p style="    width: 10%;float: left;"><a onclick="javascript:savelike(<?php echo $Data['postid'];?>, <?php echo $Data['firstname'];?>, <?php echo $this->session->userdata('userproid'); ?>);">
     <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 25px; color: cornflowerblue;"></i> 
     <span id="like_<?php echo $Data['postid'];?>">
        <?php if($Data['likes']>0){echo $Data['likes'].' Likes';}else{echo 'Like';} ?>
     </span></a>
    </p>
```

Comment: Maybe you want to ask a question?

Comment: You cant send in strings to your function like that you must quote `firstname`, or just remove them as your not using them. but what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

You miss the username and autid in Data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function savelike(storyid, username, autid)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url('site/homecontroler/savelikes');?>",
            Data: "Storyid="+storyid+"&username="+username+"&autid="+autid,
            success: function (response) {
             $("#like_"+storyid).html(response+" Likes");

            }
        });
}
</script>
```

In Html pass the values as string missing '' in firstname and autid

```
<p style="    width: 10%;float: left;"><a onclick="javascript:savelike(<?php echo $Data['postid'];?>, '<?php echo $Data['firstname'];?>', '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('userproid'); ?>');">
 <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size: 25px; color: cornflowerblue;"></i> 
 <span id="like_<?php echo $Data['postid'];?>">
    <?php if($Data['likes']>0){echo $Data['likes'].' Likes';}else{echo 'Like';} ?>
 </span></a>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you got the storyid, username, autid values in savelike function?

Comment: arguments should be quoted in javascript method , may be there is another error try to console the arguments

Comment: i have tried to make two function one is

function savelike(storyid)

another is

function savelike(storyid, username, autid)

values automaticly going to the first function.. but i am passing a3 values in html..

Comment: You can use this  savelike(storyid, username, autid) for script and pass the empty string in html like onclick=" savelike(<?php echo $Data['postid'];?>, '', '');"

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the formatting as I'm on mobile. Try defining the data to be sent like so:

```
data: {
    storyid: storyid,
    username: username,
    ...
}
```

If that doesn't work please do a console log to see if you are getting the variables. If you aren't, then the issue is obvious.

PS you also haven't properly quoted your first paramter (postid)!